# Git: show only extra/removed files between branches

Tags: git, branch

Say I have two branches `branch1` and `branch2`. I want to see a list of those files present in a branch that are absent from the other.

I know i can do:

```
 git diff --stat --color branch1 branch2
```

to see all the files and their diffs. This command comes close to what I want since it shows files not present in `branch1` as:

```
folder/file1.py              |  66 ++++++++
```

and those not present in `branch2` as:

```
folder/file2.py              |  32 -----
```

But this command also shows me the *diffs of all the other files* that have changed between branches and I want to filter those. When lots of files have changed between branches, this is inconvenient.

How can I see only those extra/removed files between branches? Basically I need to see a list that quickly allows me to say "these files are present in `branch1` and removed from `branch2` or viceversa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use `git diff --raw` for this, but I'm not sure how it holds up with renames:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 --raw | cut -f 5- -d ' ' | grep "^[AD]"
```

Here's what it does:

- `git diff branch1 branch2 --raw` basically emits a machine parsable version of `git status`.  For example:

  ```
  :: git diff 139a34^ 139a34 --raw
  :100644 100644 313c68b... 9852990... M  plugin/togglecursor.vim
  ```

  The 5th column has a status flag saying whether the file was modified (M), removed (D), or added (A).  There are others too.  Here's a snippet from `git help diff` in the [*Raw Output Format section*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_raw_output_format):

  ```
     in-place edit  :100644 100644 bcd1234... 0123456... M file0
     copy-edit      :100644 100644 abcd123... 1234567... C68 file1 file2
     rename-edit    :100644 100644 abcd123... 1234567... R86 file1 file3
     create         :000000 100644 0000000... 1234567... A file4
     delete         :100644 000000 1234567... 0000000... D file5
     unmerged       :000000 000000 0000000... 0000000... U file6
  ```
- `cut -f 5- -d ' '` says to strip off the first 4 columns of data.  So we only keep the status flag and the path that comes after it.
- Finally, `grep "^[AD]"` says to only keep lines where the file has been added or removed.

Comment: This seems to work nicely. Would you mind explaining a bit what the command does? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel I updated my answer with more information about what is happening.  Hope you find it useful!